# An error about using binplace.exe in batch-files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to remove private symbol from a symbol file using binplace.exe, I saved the following command into a batch file 'parse.bat': `binplace -a -x -s %_NTTREE%\stripped -n %_NTTREE%\full my-executable-file-name`. 
The question is: When I executed the `parse.bat` from command-line, `binplace` can generate stripped symbol file properly, but if I executed the `parse.bat` by double-click on it, `binplace` cannot generate stripped symbol file, here is the output message from binplace using `-v` option:

```
execute by double-click:
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (-s)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\stripped)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\stripped)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (-n)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\full)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\full)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe)

BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: Looking at file SystemTool.exe
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: Class bin Not found in Class Tables
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: place f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe in f:\SymbolServer\bin\SystemTool.exe
binplace f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: copy f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe to f:\SymbolServer\bin\SystemTool.exe
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: No symbols to strip from f:\SymbolServer\bin\SystemTool.exe
BINPLACE : warning BNP1536: Public symbols being copied to f:\SymbolServer\stripped\bin\exe\.
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: place f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.pdb in f:\SymbolServer\stripped\bin\exe\SystemTool.pdb
BINPLACE : warning BNP2700: Unable to copy (f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.pdb,f:\SymbolServer\stripped\bin\exe\SystemTool.pdb) 126
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: place f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.pdb in f:\SymbolServer\full\bin\exe\SystemTool.pdb
BINPLACE : warning GNA0127: Command line finished
Press any key to continue . . .

execute from command-line:
F:\SymbolServer>parse.bat
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (-s)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\stripped)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\stripped)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (-n)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\full)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer\full)
BINPLACE : warning GNA0293: Not a response file (f:\SymbolServer SystemTool.exe)

BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: Looking at file SystemTool.exe
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: Class bin Not found in Class Tables
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: place f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe in f:\SymbolServer\bin\SystemTool.exe
binplace f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: copy f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe to f:\SymbolServer\bin\SystemTool.exe
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: Symbols stripped from f:\SymbolServer\bin\SystemTool.exe into f:\SymbolServer\stripped\bin\exe\SystemTool.dbg
BINPLACE : warning BNP0000: place f:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.pdb in f:\SymbolServer\full\bin\exe\SystemTool.pdb
BINPLACE : warning GNA0127: Command line finished
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Using `symchk`, I confirmed that `SystemTool.exe` has only private symbol, the output message is listed below:

```
F:\SymbolServer>symchk /v SystemTool.exe /s .
[SYMCHK] Searching for symbols to F:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe in path .
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: .
[SYMCHK] Using search path "."
DBGHELP: No header for F:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe.  Searching for image on d
isk
DBGHELP: F:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe - OK
DBGHELP: SystemTool - private symbols & lines
         .\SystemTool.pdb
[SYMCHK] MODULE64 Info ----------------------
[SYMCHK] Struct size: 1672 bytes
[SYMCHK] Base: 0x00400000
[SYMCHK] Image size: 10293248 bytes
[SYMCHK] Date: 0x52395664
[SYMCHK] Checksum: 0x009cd39e
[SYMCHK] NumSyms: 0
[SYMCHK] SymType: SymPDB
[SYMCHK] ModName: SystemTool
[SYMCHK] ImageName: F:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe
[SYMCHK] LoadedImage: F:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe
[SYMCHK] PDB: ".\SystemTool.pdb"
[SYMCHK] CV: RSDS
[SYMCHK] CV DWORD: 0x53445352
[SYMCHK] CV Data:  D:\cwork\DriverLoader\Debug\SystemTool.pdb
[SYMCHK] PDB Sig:  0
[SYMCHK] PDB7 Sig: {444090A7-6BE8-4310-BD87-4ABCA3F8E8A9}
[SYMCHK] Age: 1
[SYMCHK] PDB Matched:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] DBG Matched:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] Line nubmers: TRUE
[SYMCHK] Global syms:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] Type Info:    TRUE
[SYMCHK] ------------------------------------
SymbolCheckVersion  0x00000002
Result              0x001f0001
DbgFilename
DbgTimeDateStamp    0x52395664
DbgSizeOfImage      0x009d1000
DbgChecksum         0x009cd39e
PdbFilename         F:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.pdb
PdbSignature        {444090A7-6BE8-4310-BD87-4ABCA3F8E8A9}
PdbDbiAge           0x00000001
[SYMCHK] [ 0x00000000 - 0x001f0001 ] Checked "F:\SymbolServer\SystemTool.exe"

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 0
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 1
```

Who can tell me why and how to resolve it.

Comment: Your command uses an environment variable that is not shown or mentioned, and we can't see your batch file, so we do not have a full picture of what is happening.

Comment: @foxidrive, thank for your post, here is my batch file:`@echo off
set _NTTREE=f:\SymbolServer
set BINPLACE_PLACEFILE=%_NTTREE%\placefile.txt

binplace -a -x -v -s %_NTTREE%\stripped -n %_NTTREE%\full %_NTTREE%\SystemTool.exe

pause`.

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to your comment, so I can paste the code.

Your code sets another variable - where is that being used?

Try it with the added `pause` command and see if it works the same at the cmd prompt and when double clicking.  Don't add anything else to it.  `It occurs to me that you may not have typed the batch file name at the command line - did you do that?`

BTW, if it still fails when double clicking then check if your path\batchname contains an `&` character, or maybe some `%` characters.

```
@echo off
set _NTTREE=f:\SymbolServer
set BINPLACE_PLACEFILE=%_NTTREE%\placefile.txt
binplace -a -x -v -s %_NTTREE%\stripped -n %_NTTREE%\full
pause
%_NTTREE%\SystemTool.exe
pause
```